# Can I set multiple 'options' with a single `:set` command spread over multiple lines?

Tags: vimrc, options, set

Is there any way to set options typed on multiple lines with a single `:set` command?

Here is a part of my vimrc:

```
se nu
se sm
se hls
```

And as you see, I have `se` on every line in which I set an option. I know that I can set the all options in one line with a single `se` but How can I set them with one `se` but with the options themselves specified on multiple lines.

e.g. I'd like to write something like:

```
se nu,
sm,
hls,
```

Comment: Your question is a bit unclear, but I think `set nu sm hls` will do what you want?

Comment: @Carpetsmoker I think the question is to add a newline between `nu` and `sm` and between `sm` and `hls` in your command which is (I think) not possible (but I don't really understand how that would be helpful to be able to do that)

Comment: no actually I know that I can set these option in one line but I want to set them in some lines with one 'se'.

Comment: I wouldn't recommend it, but it should be possible using \ at the beginning of the lines for line continuation (this depends on the `C` in `cpoptions`). Note, this is hardly readable, and using the short option form is not really recommended.

Comment: Thanks for respon. How about 'ino' & 'cnorea' options? 'cause I have many lines (about 15) that they contain this two options on start of line, Can I sum them up? or Is it good idea to sum up them?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

I'd personally recommend against doing so, but you can use Vim's "line continuation" feature for this:

```
set number
\ showmatch
\ hlsearch
```

This will be interpreted by Vim as if the contents of the lines after the backslashes were written at the end of the previous line:

```
set number showmatch hlsearch
```

Note that whitespace *before* the backslash is ignored:

```
set number
  \ showmatch
  \ hlsearch
```

See `:help line-continuation` for more details.

`ino` and `cnorea` are the short forms of the `inoremap` and `cnoreabbrev` commands. It is not possible to merge multiple map/abbreviation commands into a single command in this way: this only works with `:set` because that command already allows you to set multiple options with a single command.

Comment: Thank you so muck for clear, so I will use of default and standard option :)))